# How do i avoid text overlapping in td?

Tags: html, css, pd4ml

[image]

I have genertaed a pdf from html using pd4ml jar. The image shown is the resultant pdf that has text in td overlapping each other. the code is as follows

```
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td class="reportHeading" align="middle"><b>$title</b></td>
           <td class="reportLogo"><img height="${logoHeight}" src='$logo'></img></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and the css is

```
    .reportHeading {
        font-size: 15pt;
        text-align:left;
        height:auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .reportLogo {
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:2px; 
        padding-left:2px; 
        padding-top:2px;
        padding-bottom:2px;
    }
```

I don't want to add **overflow:hidden** as it will hide the text. I want to show the text completely along with the logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it sweet and simple. Just add below **CSS**. Thanks

```
.reportHeading b {
   line-height: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `"overflow-x : scroll"`. 
But you will get a horizontal scroll bar, if the content is overflowing

Answer (score 0):

You can this `style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto;"`code in div

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve <br> Eve
      </td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnsonkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with two div inside the td
Each div had in line block 
Try to add padding zero for text content div element

Try it and post the result image as you did above 
If you can post a simple working code, it would help

See [inline-block sample](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_nav)

Answer (score 0):

apply Line height to your class "reportHeading" text.

```
.reportHeading{
line-height: 25px;
}
```